# How to allow to run google script on a protected sheet (in a spreadsheet) [Can't use trigger and web app]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, filtering, protected

I'm coding a script for a spreadsheet. This script creates a menu. 
Then by choosing an option in this menu a function (which uses API) will run in order to filter some columns and hide others.

The problem is:

This sheet is protected (because shared with coworkers) but I want to allow people to run the script, which is impossible without the permission.

---

I already looked at different solutions:

- Using a trigger: Doesn't work because a trigger can't correctly call a function which uses API (yes, my functions use API).
- Web App: When the script is run from the spreadsheet, the script is run as the current user, not the script editor. (the web app is efficient if the user uses the HTML page.)
- Remove protection -> run the function -> Re-add protection: Can't modify the protection without permission, which is logical.
- Add the current user in the list editor -> run the function -> Remove the current user from the list editor: Can't modify the editor list without permission, which is logical.

---

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Installed triggers can use functions which require authorization. Simple triggers cannot. `function onEdit(e)` is a simple trigger function. `function isRunOnEdit(e)`, which has an `onEdit` trigger created for it by a user or programmatically, is an installed trigger.

Comment: The web app doesn't have to run as the current user, it can run under the editor's authorization.

Comment: Furthermore, you can show your web app in the sidebar of google sheets using this [option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode#DEFAULT)

Comment: Thanks a lot this answer helps me a lot !! Now I have put my menu in few cell thanks to drop down.

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible to make a trigger work by running a script ?

Comment: @YvanBoudeau  [Yes, programmatic creation of triggers is possible.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/)

Comment: You might consider having the sheet unprotected, but hidden. You can have the triggers firing on the hidden sheet and display the data on another public but protect sheet using `=importrange()` or `=query()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain that I have not seen a good workaround.  Google should know that in a collaborative environment that the owner would create script and want users to be able to run those scripts while at the same time not messing with formulas or cells that you desire to protect.  The only way I have found to solve this on the sheet itself is to Unprotect and then Protect the cell or range you are making modifications to during the script run.  Do be mindful that if the script fails in the middle (after you have unprotected it) the cell remain unprotected.  Might want to run within a "try" script.

Answer (score -1):

Are you the spreadsheet owner? 
If no, you are not authorized to bound an apps script on it.
But you can make a copy of the spreadsheet by duplicate it and save in your drive.

If the spreadsheet is created by you yourself, maybe you created it by another username. If it does, log in by that user and change the sharing option to allow the specific user can edit it.

Comment: This does not answer the question.